# How to reset -moz-user-select to be selectable?

Tags: html, css

I have applied `* {-moz-user-select: none;}` to the main stylesheet, because there are more unselectable elements than those that are selectable. I then tried to set `-moz-user-select: auto;` to an input, but it does not work. I have also tried the value of `text` and `all`, both do not work.

Also it seems that `user-select` does not work in IE9 and Opera 10.62 or am I missing something?

I am trying to disable selection by default for all browsers, and then explicitly enable it for some elements like input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why oh why are you using the universal selector? Please, you *have* to be more specific with your selectors than that.

As to the answer to your question, reading the [**MDC documentations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select) carefully, you'll see that the `-moz-none` value is the one you're looking for, not `none`:

> #### -moz-none
>
> The text of the element and sub-elements cannot be selected, 
>   but selection can be enabled on sub-elements using `-moz-user-select: text`.

Set this to the universal selector, and you'll be fine. See this demo to see it working live: http://jsfiddle.net/KqJ7R/

Comment: According to MDN since Firefox 21 -moz-none and none are the same.

Comment: Works in Chrome too, just replace -moz with -webkit and use `none` for the value as suggested by @BrianDiPalma